# 2:12: parse error on input `count'

Tags: haskell, io

The question is:
One of the famous proofs of modern mathematics is Georg Cantor's demonstration that the set of rational numbers is enumerable. The proof works by using an explicit enumeration of rational numbers as shown in the diagram below.

```
1/1 1/2 1/3 1/4 1/5 ...
2/1 2/2 2/3 2/4
3/1 3/2 3/3
4/1 4/2
5/1
```

In the above diagram, the first term is 1/1, the second term is 1/2, the third term is 2/1, the fourth term is 3/1, the fifth term is 2/2, and so on.

You are to write a program that will read a list of numbers in the range from 1 to 107 and will print for each number the corresponding term in Cantor's enumeration as given below. No blank line should appear after the last number. The input list contains a single number per line and will be terminated by end-of-file. No more than 30 numbers will appear in the input file.

The code I wrote is:

```
stepOver = do [left num den dir]
   count <- getLine
   let left =  count' -1
   if left == 0
    then putStrLn [num den]
    let newleft = left -1
        case (stepOver num) of
            1 -> if dir == up
                stepOver = [newleft 1 (den + 1) down]
                stepOver = [newleft 2 (den - 1) down]
        case (stepOver den) of
            1 -> if dir == down
                stepOver = [newleft (num + 1) 1 down]
                stepOver = [newleft (num - 1) 2 down]
        case (stepOver dir) of
            up -> stepOver = [newleft (num - 1) (den + 1) dir]
        case (stepOver dir) of
            down -> stepOver = [newleft (num + 1) (den - 1) dir]
```

so, could you tell me why I am wrong?

Comment: Do you mean `stepOver left num den dir = do` instead of `stepOver = do [left num den dir]`?

Comment: Your syntax only slightly resembles Haskell. What do you mean by square brackets?

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to read up on some [Haskell](http://www.learnyouahaskell.com). You're misunderstanding some basic syntax.

First off, `case` works like this.

```
case expression of
  pat1 -> expr1
  pat2 -> expr2
  ...

case someBool of
   True -> 1
   False -> 2
```

Next is `if`.

```
if someBool then expr1 else expr2
```

The `else` is **not** optional.

```
if True then 1 else 2
```

Up next, `let`

```
let pat1 = expr1
    pat2 = expr2
    ...
in expr

let foo = 1
    bar = 2
in foo + bar
```

Finally, `do`

```
do
  someExpr
  let pat = expr
  pat <- someExpr
do
  putStrLn "Hello World"
  let x = 1
  myLine <- getLine
```

Now once you've figured out some of the syntax, you should be able to fix your code.

Edit:

Variables in Haskell are immutable, writing `foo = bar` in a `do` block isn't going to mutate it. It's just a syntax error and you have several in your code.